不定期でローカルのDifyにログインできなくなってしまう
問題
発現条件は不明ですがとあるタイミングでローカルのDifyにログインできなくなってしまいました。
(正式には"Invallid email or password."と右上に表示されログインできない状態です。)
実行環境

OS: Windows 11 -WSL2 Ubuntu
Docker: 27.2.0

今まで試したこと

パスワードのリセット

"パスワードを忘れた"の部分でメールアドレスを入力しましたがリセットメールは来ませんでした

これは.envでメール配信の設定をしていないので正常かと思われます。


docker exec -it docker-api-1 flask reset-passwordコマンドでのリセット

Difyのドキュメントにローカルでの初期化後のパスワードリセット方法が記載されていたため実行しましたが該当のメールアドレスのアカウントは見つからないとのエラーが出ました。




ログインページでの”管理者アカウントの作成”ボタンのクリック

もし、すべてのデータが消えていて初期状態ならば"管理者アカウントの作成"からアカウントの作成ができると思いましたが、ページの変移が一瞬で元のページに戻ってしまいました。



